# Replace all occurrences of ";;" in a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, replace

I'm searching for a one line trick to do the following :

I have this string `"Car;;;;Plane"` and want this result `"Car;NULL;NULL;NULL;Plane"`.

I'm doing `myString.replaceAll(";;", ";NULL;");` but the result is `"Car;NULL;;NULL;Plane"`, I guess it find only two occurrences of the pattern, I want it to consider as three occurrences.

What is the best / quickest way to do this ?

Comment: Refer to the linked question, which also provides a more general approach. `.replaceAll(";(?!$)", "$0NULL")`.

Comment: It contains for example `"Plane;;Fruit;;;;Car"` and the result should be `"Plane;NULL;Fruit;NULL;NULL;NULL;Car"`. But thank you, the accepted answer works well as it should. I edited the question"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following code with positive "look-arounds":

```
System.out.println(
    ";;;;"
    .replaceAll("(?<=;)(?=;)", "NULL")
);
```

**Output**

```
;NULL;NULL;NULL;
```

**Notes**

- Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- Essentially, your pattern here is made of two non-capturing groups that look both behind and ahead the capturing point. If both conditions are met ("preceded by `;`" and "followed by `;`"), the replacement argument (`"NULL"`) will be inserted between the two.

Comment: Regular expressions never fail to amaze and confuse me.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson that seems to be their main purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another shorter variant:

```
String repl = ";;;;".replaceAll("(?<!^);", "NULL$0");
//> ;NULL;NULL;NULL;
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NL4PBz/3)

- `(?<!^);` uses a negative lookbehind to match match every `;` except the first one.
- `$0` is back-reference of full matched string.